# Bash Script for using grep in an if statement with a for loop

Tags: bash, shell, selinux

I am trying to make my bash script ssh into each server and then grep Selinux=enforcing/replace with Selinux=permissive. The issue I am facing is it checks the first server and but not the second server. I believe it arises from my if statement.

```
#!/bin/bash

selinux_path=/opt/configtest
hosts=(server1 server2)


for my_hosts in "${hosts[@]}"
do
    ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" root@${my_hosts} "
        if [ $(grep -c SELINUX=enforcing $selinux_path) -ne 0 ]
        then 
            echo "------------------------------------------------"
            echo "${my_hosts}"
            echo "------------------------------------------------"
            sed -i 's/SELINUX=enforcing/SELINUX=permissive/g' ${selinux_path}
            echo "Selinux has been changed to permissive"
            cat ${selinux_path}
        else
            echo "------------------------------------------------"
            echo "${my_hosts}"
            echo "------------------------------------------------"
            echo "Selinux has already been changed to permissive"
            cat ${selinux_path}
        fi    
        "
    
done
```

Comment: The loop should execute twice (use `set -x` to verify this), but I would expect from this code that you get several error messages (such as _command not found_) in each operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest `"` inside `"`. If you want to give multiline input to `ssh`, the easiest way is with a here-doc.

```
#!/bin/bash

selinux_path=/opt/configtest
hosts=(server1 server2)


for my_hosts in "${hosts[@]}"
do
    ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" root@${my_hosts} <<EOF
        if grep -q SELINUX=enforcing "$selinux_path"
        then 
            echo "------------------------------------------------"
            echo "${my_hosts}"
            echo "------------------------------------------------"
            sed -i 's/SELINUX=enforcing/SELINUX=permissive/g' ${selinux_path}
            echo "Selinux has been changed to permissive"
            cat "${selinux_path}"
        else
            echo "------------------------------------------------"
            echo "${my_hosts}"
            echo "------------------------------------------------"
            echo "Selinux has already been changed to permissive"
            cat "${selinux_path}"
        fi    
EOF
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify the full path for grep, echo, sed and cat?